# Invalid sender Id while getting device token

Tags: java, android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am doing Firebase cloud messaging setup in my Android App. I am not doing it first time.I have done it many times. But this time I am getting a strange error "Invalid Sender ID" while trying to get device token.I have never used any Sender Id in My Project ever except Project number which is by default present in google-services.json file.Please help me out of this

.I am using this method to generate token.I have added google-services.json file in my Project

```
 FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<InstanceIdResult> task) {
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(WelcomeActivity.this,task.getException().getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.w("getInstanceId failed", task.getException());
                        return;
                    }

                    // Get new Instance ID token
                    String token = task.getResult().getToken();
                    Log.v("sssskkkk",token);

                }
            });
```

I am using following dependencies in my Project

```
 implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
api fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
testImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2')

implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
implementation 'me.relex:circleindicator:1.2.2@aar'
implementation 'org.immutables:gson:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'

implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation 'com.borjabravo:readmoretextview:2.0.1'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
implementation 'com.github.mabbas007:TagsEditText:1.0.5'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'


implementation 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:28.0.0'

implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:4.2.0'
```

I am pretty sure that I am not missing anything in implementation of Firebase cloud messaging.Also when I am using same google-services.json in different project with same package name then all working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah finally I solved it after spending around 30 hours on it.That code was done by previous developer and I found that there were two google-services.json files, one in app folder and another in debug folder so Sender ID's were mismatching in it.So I would like to suggest all those who are getting this error:-

1. Should check that you have copied your file in correct folder that is app.
2. Should check the file is correct and matches with latest downloaded google-services.json file in FCM
3. Should check that is there any duplicate file of google-services.json present in your project?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same exception.
(`java.io.IOException: INVALID_SENDER`)

I had succeeded to get the registration token but after removing the firebase project and re-create a firebase project I started to get the `Invalid sender` exception.

I confirmed that I copied the correct `google-services.json` file but the exception happened.

The solution is simple.
Just **delete** below generated **google-services** folder.

```
Project_Name\app\build\generated\res\google-services
```

If you delete the folder and rebuild the project, the correct google-services folder is made from the current  `google-services.json` file.
Now you can get firebase registration token.

Comment: it can be done by `gradlew clean` command too